# PHP to Ruby snippet translation needed (Basic Authorization and URL access)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need this in Ruby:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("user:pass")
    )
));

$output = file_get_contents("http://example.com/file.php", false, $context);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean 'PHP to Ruby'

Comment: @Abe: That's what the title says? ;)

Comment: @Ryan I see what you did there. Guess I could've done it myself with my amazing new editing privileges!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html).

```
require 'net/http'

output = nil
Net::HTTP.start('example.com') {|http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/file.php')
  req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
  response = http.request(req)
  output = response.body
}
```

Comment: I needed to create a post with custom headers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36928680/396429