# HTTP.post_form in Ruby with custom headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post

Im trying to use Nets/HTTP to use `POST` and put in a custom user agent. I've typically used `open-uri` but it cant do `POST` can it?

I use

```
resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, query)
```

How would I change this to throw custom headers in?

Edit my query is:

```
query = {'a'=>'b'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this, for example:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('domain.com', 80)
path = '/url'

data = 'form=data&more=values'
headers = {
  'Cookie' => cookie,
  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
```

Comment: If you already have your query params URL-encoded, this is probably just as good as mine. Mine sets the `Content-Type` header and converts a query Hash, though.

Comment: Can I use {parama=value, paramb=value2} type info for the input (How would I serialize it) I tried it and it seems awesome! Except I don't know how to serialize?

Comment: Got it I used addressable/uri

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `post_form` to do that, but you can do it like this:

```
uri = URI(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data(query)
req['User-Agent'] = 'Some user agent'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end

case res
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
  # OK
else
  res.value
end
```

(Read the [net/http documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) for more info)

Comment: I gave it a shot I had to change uri.hostname to uri.host though. Odd because its exactly this in the ruby docs.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: (`URI#hostname` seems to have been added in 1.9.3, which I was assuming you were using. Sorry about that.)

Answer (score 5):

I needed to post json to a server with custom headers. Other solutions I looked at didn't work for me. Here was my solution that worked.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://sample.website.com/api/auth")
params = {'email' => 'someemail@email.com'}
headers = {
    'Authorization'=>'foobar',
    'Date'=>'Thu, 28 Apr 2016 15:55:01 MDT',
    'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
    'Accept'=>'application/json'}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.post(uri.path, params.to_json, headers)
output = response.body
puts output
```

Thanks due to Mike Ebert's tumblr:
http://mikeebert.tumblr.com/post/56891815151/posting-json-with-nethttp

Answer (score -1):

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse('https://your_url.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ca_path='/etc/pki/tls/certs/'
http.ca_file='/etc/pki/tls/certs/YOUR_CERT_CHAIN_FILE'
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("YOUR_CERT)_FILE"))
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("YOUR_KEY_FILE"))

#SSLv3 is cracked, and often not allowed
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2

#### This is IMPORTANT
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

#Crete the POST request
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.add_field 'X_REMOTE_USER', 'soap_remote_user'
request.add_field 'Accept', '*'
request.add_field 'SOAPAction', 'soap_action'
request.body = request_payload

#Get Response
response = http.request(request)

#Review Response
puts response.body
```