# SocketError : HiPay Integration in Rails app (Payment API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, https, net-http

I'm trying to implement HiPay API for my checkout process.

In my controller i do :

```
 http = Net::HTTP.new("https://test-www.hipay.com/")
 @response = http.post("/order", xml)
```

and i have this error :

```
SocketError in XController#new<br>
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I build my xml in my controller like this :

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

xml.HIPAY_MAPI_SimplePayment do
  xml.HIPAY_MAPI_PaymentParams do
    xml.login("7379")
    xml.password("1911")
    xml.itemAccount("7379")
    xml.taxAccount("7379")
    xml.insuranceAccount("7379")

    ...
end
```

I dont know what is my problem.

Does anyone have some experience with HiPay API ? May be https problem ?

Im in trouble with this API integration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use HTTPS you should specify some additional parameters. Your snippet would work for a non-secure connection but for SSL look at the [official documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS), this helpful [HTTP cheat sheet](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) or these SO questions: [Using Net::HTTP.get for an https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786779/using-nethttp-get-for-an-https-url),  [Ruby https POST with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269224/ruby-https-post-with-headers)

Comment: Thanks you @rkon ! These topics were useful. Especially the first with https.