# How to create POST Request in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xapi

I have functionality where I need send delivery payload with static basic token and additional header.

```
scope = "xapi:read" # some require xapi:read, some require xapi:all
client_auth_header = "Basic <insert token here>"
client_version_header = "1.0.3"
client_site = "<Provided by client>"
```

I need to do this with post request

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://client-url/data/xAPI/agents \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic XYZABC' \
  --header 'X-Experience-API-Version: 1.0.3'
```

How do I write a post request in ruby ?

with something like this

```
client.post("/xAPI/statements", body: data.to_json, headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" })
```

what should I replace the client with ?

Comment: I would probably start by searching for "ruby make http request".

Comment: there's about a million answers regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269224/ruby-https-post-with-headers

Answer (score 1):

The [httparty gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/httparty) supports a very similar API to what you described here, with `HTTParty.post`.